# ThrowAway Environment and Scoping

Tags: scoping, contexts, clear

I want to be able to Get a .wl file. Run some functions (who will do their job working on some separate files that are being written away). And then return to some clean slate so that I can repeat this process with another .wl file and some other functions. This is close to using Quit between these two actions but I want

1. To keep some basic definitions or at worst automatically redefine them after we obtained a new empty state.
2. To be able to have multiple of these inputs in one notebook and have it be runable as a whole.

Quit would fail at both these things. My solution for now is to define the basic definitions, protect them and then use functions such as

```
run[wlfile] := Module[{},
 Quiet@ClearAll["Global`*"];
 Get[(fileName[wlfile])];
 ComputationsUsingDefinitionsInWLFile[a][b][c];
 Quiet@ClearAll["Global`*"];
]
```

Here `a`,`b`,`c` would be set globally and protected as would `fileName[file_]` (defined as a function that points to the correct file) and `run`.

Is there some scoping construct that would do a better job at this?

(I don't know the exact symbols that will be affected by the .wl file (and there will be many) so I can't specifically Block them.)

---

Ideally the solutions can be used in the following form

```
throwAwayEnvironment[codeToRun,getCode]
```

where the first argument contains the code to be run after performing the `getCode` which Gets definitions (which could be necessary for `codeToRun` ). The answer by Carl seemed to be able to be written in this form, but I ran into trouble due to the fact that any function called inside `` Internal ` WithLocalSettings `` got saved to the wrong environment and did not get removed afterwards. First calling all functions as `Symbol["f"]` inside `WithLocalSettings` solves this. However, I then need to automate the finding of functions inside `codeToRun` and run Symbol["function"] for all of them and all of that without the function first being saved as `Global` variables. This last seems to be impossible since this is done instantly. Note that if you use `Symbol[ToString[f]]`, this already no longer works since `f` will already have been made into a `global` variable.

Answer (score 9):

You can block [`$Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Context) and then read your file:

```
Block[{$Context="ThrowawayContext`"}, 
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        Null,

        Get[(fileName[wlfile])];
        ComputationsUsingDefinitionsInWLFile[a][b][c],

        Remove["ThrowawayContext`*"]
    ]
]
```

All new symbols will have the context `` "ThrowawayContext`" ``, and the `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` third argument makes sure that the new symbols are always removed (the third argument is abort protected).

**Update**

I don't know that you can create a function that automatically parses new symbols into a given context. On the other hand, you can make a [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) style that does this. An example [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) object that meets your requirements:

```
Cell[
    BoxData[""],
    "Input",
    CellContext -> Cell,
    CellProlog :> ($ContextPath = {"Global`", "System`", $Context}),
    CellEpilog :> Remove["`*"],
    Background -> GrayLevel[.9]
]
```

The key ingredients are:

1. `CellContext -> Cell`

This causes new symbols to be created in a unique context

2. `` CellProlog :> ($ContextPath = {"Global`", "System`", $Context}) ``

With the above [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath), new symbols will only be created when they are not present in the "Global`" or "System`" context.

3. `` CellEpilog :> Remove["`*"] ``

The above epilog removes all symbols in the current context, namely the new symbols that have been created.

The easiest way to be able to make use of the above is to add a "Throwaway" style to the style sheet that inherits from the "Input" style. Here is a function that adds the above style to a notebook's style sheet:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Throwaway", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Input"]],
            StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"Input"},
            CellContext->Cell,
            CellProlog:>($ContextPath={"Global`",$Context,"System`"}),
            CellEpilog:>Quiet[Remove["`*"]],
            Background->GrayLevel[0.9]
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["Input"],
            StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab"->"Throwaway"}
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

After evaluating the above, you can create a new "Input" cell, and then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the start of the cell to convert it to a "Throwaway" cell (this is the point of the `StyleKeyMapping` options). The background will change to a light gray indicating that you now have a "Throwaway" cell. Then enter your code, and evaluate. For example, with a normal "Input" cell:

```
NameQ["a"]
```

> False

So, there is no symbol `a`. Then, create a "Throwaway" cell, and enter the following:

```
Get[StringToStream["a[i_] := Print[\"test\"]"]]
Print[DownValues[a]]
a[2]
```

> {HoldPattern[a[i_]]:>Print[test]}
>
> test

Finally, check that "a" has not been added to the global name space:

```
NameQ["a"]
```

> False

Comment: Thank you! This is almost what I want. Only there is still something happening that I'm confused about. Say I replace ComputationsUsingDefinitionsInWLFile with a function that can be found in the WL file (or some function that calls multiple of these). Than this (those) functions will not be removed (the further ones it calls within the WL file do seem to be removed). What is happening and how can I avoid this?

Comment: @Kvothe If I understand correctly, I think your function acquires the Global` context while the input is parsed. To avoid this, use ``ThrowawayContext`function`` instead of `function`.

Comment: Great! Thank you! One last (unimportant) question: is there any way to write this last as something like \$Context \`function, I mean using the fact that we already defined \$Context inside the block. (for example ToExpression[\$Context] doesn't work).

Comment: @Kvothe You could use Symbol["function"], which will create the symbol function in the current context if it doesn't already exist on the context path.

Comment: Your solutions works in that case. However, in practice it is not really workable. The problem is that I want to be able to use this as a  scoping environment function like Module and Block. However, I would need to use Symbol["f"] for any function that gets used inside it. Moreover, I can't even use Symbol[ToString[f]] since this seems to already introduce f in the wrong context before it is converted to a string creating the problem I had before. This means that all functions would need to be written by hand in string form and eliminates all hope of some automation.

Comment: @Kvothe I think you can just add an outside Block for those symbols? Having a complete working example of what you want to do would be helpful.

Comment: Indeed I can probably use a block for those variables but the point is that it seems to me that a general solution should be possible (and would definitely be extremely useful for tons of applications!). I want an environment where everything gets deleted afterwards. If I have to look myself which symbols get definitions inside the code the environment becomes kind of useless. So I'm hoping for a function where I do not need to pre-declare what functions will occur and will still delete all new definitions.

Comment: (cont'ed) Your suggestion does exactly that except that it does not delete functions found in ComputationsUsingDefinitionsInWLFile. So I'm hoping there is some way to make it do that. I think you can also understand how much nicer a general tool that can really be used in a similar way to block would be than one where you have to first find out and list all functions you might use within the scoping construct.

Comment: Minimal working example can simply be a file file.wl which contains `a[i_]:=Print["test"]`, we then want `throwawayEnvironment[a[2],Get[file.wl]]` to output `"test"` and return to a state where `a` has no value (if it had no value before). Of course your solutions solves this if we specifically write `Symbol["a"]` instead of a, but I'm looking to add one layer on top of this so that you do not need to do this by hand. Instead `throwawayEnvironment` should somehow do this. This last step is important because only if it works in general does it become a really useful scoping construct.

Comment: Otherwise my notebook will contain your code 20 times, once for each different file and function I call. If a notebook contains almost the exact same block of code multiple times I think it is a sure sign that one is doing something wrong and find a way to define it as a function.